# Which IP Address do I use to connect with devices outside my network?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, internet, ip, remote-connection

Which IP Address do I use when I want to connect with another device out of my Network/Router?
For example, Remote Desktop, or anything else where you need an IP address to connect.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have written this almost entirely in Title Case, then set it as a headline?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is purely about "what IP to connect to" for remote desktop and other devices in your network, the answer is simple...

Open a web browser and go to any of these sites:

https://www.ipchicken.com/
https://www.whatismyip.com/
https://www.moanmyip.com/

Any of these sites will tell you your public IP address, assuming you are not behind a [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) network. This is the IP address you would connect to remotely in most cases for consumer users, assuming your ISP supports this.

Note that this information, although useful, is not sufficient to get services like Remote Desktop to work... You would also have to do some pre-configuration on your PC and setup port forwarding in your router, but those issues were not in your question.

Comment: There is a little bit of a problem, the websites doesn't give me my ip address it gives the ip to my ips(the company we are getting the internet from(every device got the same ip so how does for example remote desktop know which pc to connect to?)) or is this not a problem? Thanks For The Help!!!

Comment: @Willy32 I don't think you understand how this works, of course every device will have the same public IP address, typically you have one and all devices in your network share it. You need to setup port forwarding in your router for the specific service you want. There is significantly more to this than just finding out your public IP address, but that wasn't part of your question.

Comment: @Willy32 You haven’t clearly described what you are trying to accomplish. And it is apparent that you are very far off from a clear understanding of how this works. Go edit your question and describe exactly what you are trying to do - give an example. Then we could point you in the right direction or better describe what it is you need to learn to make this happen.

Comment: @Willy32 How you set up your network to handle incoming connections to the right IP address is a different question from how you find out what IP address devices outside your network should use to connect to devices inside your network.

Comment: Thanks For Everyones Help I Think I Have An Idea Now How To Fix This. :)